# Is it possible to disable Javascript without reloading the page in modern Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript

I seem to remember that, in the past, when one disabled Javascript in Firefox, it would immediately stop all previous-loaded scripts and event handlers from running.

However, I am now running Firefox 51 on Ubuntu Linux, and I discovered that setting `javascript.enabled` to false in `about:config` still allows already-running scripts to run until the next page refresh.

Is there some mechanism to disable Javascript immediately **without reloading the page** in modern Firefox?

Comment: Use an older version of Firefox and maybe try to verify the behavior beforehand? Why do you have this requirement?

Comment: @Seth,  I just want to read the rendered content without executing event handlers on every click and mouse over event.  Also,  the site constantly make Ajax requests as well,  which I find wasteful if I'm just trying to read the contents.  Unfortunately the initial rendering requires js, so disable after refresh is not an option.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply go to your **dev-tools**, in the **Debugger** Panel, and then click the Pause button <kbd>**||**</kbd> or press <kbd>F8</kbd> :

[image: Screencast of the dev-tools]
(screenscast from FF54 on osX)

This will immediately stop all execution of javascript in the current page.

Comment: This makes the rest of the page non usable.

Comment: That is,  I can't scroll the page or do anything else.

Comment: @merlin2011 This should not disable scrolling on the page, but other features like mouse events (even on CSS) will be blocked too. But you should have a complete access of the current DOM through the js console.

Comment: I'm trying to use the page as an ordinary user,  as if the current page was simply a static page instead of one rendered by js.

Comment: @merlin2011, then `var blob = new Blob([new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.documentElement)]);
window.open(URL.createObjectURL(blob));` once the page has loaded, and in dev-tools preferences of the opened pop-up check "Disable JavaScript". But I don't understand why you would need to try a page without js when js is needed to render the page...